# Save the data in Realm database by clicking a button

Tags: android, realm

I want to save data to Realm database by clicking button
I try but it don't work

the class is:

```
final     EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameET);

final EditText in_stock = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.avibleET);

final     EditText price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.priceET);

final         EditText size = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sizeET);

final EditText color = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.colorET);

   Button buadd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

 buadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {

            stuff s=new stuff();

            s.setName(name.getText().toString());

            s.setPrice(price.getText().toString());

            s.setIn_stock(in_stock.getText().toString());

            s.setColor(color.getText().toString());

            s.setSize(size.getText().toString());

        //working with database

        Realm.init(getApplicationContext());

        Realm realm=Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        realm.beginTransaction();

        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(s);

        realm.commitTransaction();

  Toast.makeText(context.class,"the stuff has been added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show;
```

but when I run it and press the button it says: unfortunately the app has stopped

Comment: well, look at the error

Comment: Have you tried looking at the error in the logcat tab?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your Time to Unix time and save to Realm.

Or parse time to object as

```
data class Date(val year, val day, val hours, val minutes, val seconds)
```

Comment: Where shall I add this code? Can you please clarify more?